# consulta WHERE condicionada por parámetros de búsqueda

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Formulario]Quiero realizar una consulta en donde me muestre un resultado al seleccionar una ciudad o al seleccionar un mes o buscar por el `id_nodo` o buscar por ciudad y mes que me muestre todos los nodos que hay en esa ciudad ese mes, adjunto una imagen de mi formulario para que me puedan comprender mejor.

```
SELECT * FROM huawei_gestion_proyectos 
WHERE (CIUDAD ='$CIUDAD' 
    OR MES_DESTINO = '$MES_DESTINO' 
    OR ID_NODO = '$ID_NODO') 
    OR (CIUDAD ='$CIUDAD' 
    AND MES_DESTINO = '$MES_DESTINO')
```

Comment: Cuando dices ciudad O mes O nodo O ciudad Y el mes. Que quieres preguntar con ello exactamente? Adjunta una pequeña data y como debería quedar para entender como debe ser el WHERE de tu sentencia.

Comment: No esta claro cual es el resultado esperado. Edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y que esperas como resultado.

Comment: tengo un formulario con 2 select y un input type=search(ID_NODO), quiero que al seleccionar una ciudad oprima en buscar y me arroje el resultado de esa ciudad seleccionada, lo mismo con el mes o nodo; o si quiero buscar por mes y ciudad me muestre todos los nodos de esa ciudad en el mes seleccionado

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código `PHP` en donde realizas las consultas?¿Qué es lo que no funciona como esperas?

Comment: No me funciona la consulta al querer buscar por ciudad y mes.                                                                             
                                                                                                                 
    <?php 
    $rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
    huawei_gestion_proyectos 
    WHERE (CIUDAD ='$CIUDAD' 
    OR MES_DESTINO = '$MES_DESTINO' 
    OR ID_NODO = '$ID_NODO') 
    OR (CIUDAD ='$CIUDAD' 
    AND MES_DESTINO = '$MES_DESTINO')", $conexion);
   $num_registros = mysql_num_rows($rst_informe);
   ?>

Comment: son consultas diferentes que tendrias que verificar antes de hacer tu select   Si el usuario selecciona las 3 opciones de busqueda debe ser esta la busqueda   SELECT * FROM huawei_gestion_proyectos 
WHERE (CIUDAD ='$CIUDAD' 
    and MES_DESTINO = '$MES_DESTINO' 
    and ID_NODO = '$ID_NODO')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes crear una consulta base y concatenar la condición (`WHERE`) en función a los valores que ingresa el usuario en el formulario.

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM huawei_gestion_proyectos ";

if (isset($ciudad, $mes_destino) && $ciudad != "" && $mes_destino != "") {
    $consulta .= "WHERE ciudad = ? AND mes_destino = ?";
} elseif (isset($ciudad) && $ciudad != "") {
    $consulta .= "WHERE ciudad = ?";
} elseif (isset($mes_destino) && $mes_destino != "") {
    $consulta .= "WHERE mes_destino = ?";
} elseif (isset($id_nodo) && $id_nodo != "") {
    $consulta .= "WHERE id_nodo = ?";
} else {
    $mensaje = "Debes elegir una ciudad, un mes de destino o escribir el id del nodo";
}
```

Comment: Probé con el código que pusiste Matías pero no me funciono, tengo una duda; el signo "`?`" se supone que es la variable o tendría que declarar la variable tipo:  `$CIUDAD`, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Tenes que reemplazar los signos de interrogación `?` por las variables. Te sugiero que leas sobre [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: De acuerdo lo revisare y despues te cuento, gracias