# Consulta con Opciones MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy trabajando en un buscador en el que puedo tener dos opciones de busqueda. La cuestion esta en como hago para hacer la consulta de acuerdo a los valores que tiene la seleccion.

```
<select>
    <option>Selecciona una Opcion</option>
    <option value="1">n id</option>
    <option value="2">Telefono</option>
</select>
```

La consulta deberia ser:

> SELECT*FROM gente WHERE *"aqui iria la opcion (id o telefono)"* LIKE $variable.

Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: He consultado en google y no he encontrado mucho y en mi conocimiento he intentado recoger el valor en una variable y asi pero no me funciona

Comment: Hola, puedes dar algun ejemplo de lo que has hecho. Las opciones se deben de seleccionar las dos siempre o puede el usuario seleccionar una opcion y la otra no.

Comment: Las opciones como estan en el codigo y en la tabla de la base tengo una columna que es la de id y otra de telefono y yo como usuario de eso tengo que escoger solo una opcion y conforme a la que yo seleccione me haga la consulta.

Comment: Por favor mostra el codigo que genera esa consulta, el codigo PHP. Lo que tenes que hacer, es construir la consulta dinamicamente

Comment: SELECT*FROM gente WHERE "aqui iria la opcion (id o telefono)" LIKE $variable esta es la consulta que tengo

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91409/consulta-where-condicionada-por-par%C3%A1metros-de-b%C3%BAsqueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejare un ejemplo que espero te guie:

primero necesitas tener un form donde mostrar tus opciones de consulta o filtro en tu caso es un select:

```
<form action="consultar.php" method="POST">
<select name="filtro" id="filtro" required>
   <option selected disabled>Seleccione:</option>
    <option value="1">Id</option>
    <option value="2">Telefono</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" required>
<input type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

Archivo que recibe tu filtro o parametro de busqueda(**consulta.php**):

```
<?php
$filtro = $_POST['filtro'];
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
if($filtro == 1){
$query =" SELECT * FROM gente WHERE id LIKE $variable ";
}
if($filtro == 2){
$query =" SELECT * FROM gente WHERE telefono LIKE $variable ";
}
...
...
..

?>
```

lo que se hace en el archivo es recibir el parametro enviado por tu form, luego mediante un if en este caso valido el filtro o parametro y segun ello armo o creo la sentencia sql($query)...

espero te sirva de guia..!!

Comment: Como haces para recoger el valor en filtro?

Comment: recoges mediante el metodo post, dado que asi lo determino en el form...es decir aqui:...$filtro = $_POST['filtro'];

Comment: Es decir que el termino "filtro" va a aparecer solo en el codigo php y no en el html

Comment: si te fijas.. aqui: <select name="filtro" id="filtro" required>...yo coloco un name..el cual luego recibo en un archivo php(consulta.php) y mediante el metodo post recibo ..$filtro = $_POST['filtro'];

Comment: en este caso puse filtro como nombre al parametro de busqueda de tu select..pero si deseas cambiarlo no hay problema.. puedes ponerlo como deees..

Comment: Vale no me habia fijado en ese pequeño detalle, gracias Tegito123

Comment: de nada y espero te haya servido..recuerda todo es intentando..error..tras error...suerte..!!

Answer (score 1):

Con PHP y jQuery:

```
<select>
<option id="opcion">Selecciona una Opcion</option>
<option value="1">n id</option>
<option value="2">Telefono</option>
</select>

<script>
opv = $("#opcion").val(); 
$.post( "accion.php", { op: opv}, function( data ) {
});
</script>
```

accion.php

```
<?php
$opv = $_POST["op"];
$campo="";

switch($opv)
{
    case 1:
    $campo=" campo_id ";
    break;  
    case 2:
    $campo=" campo_telefono ";
    break;
}

$str= "SELECT * FROM gente WHERE $campo LIKE ...."
?>
```

Comment: Pues la necesidad esta en que si se quieren en un futuro 10 opciones no estar creando 10 "name=", "value=" ,"$_POST[]", "SELECT * FROM" ; solo eso, gracias!